# each loop should only run once when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to hide a div when a button is clicked and then show the next div with the same class. I have tried using this code, but when I do this, the next div that I want shown also fades out.

```
 $('.arrow:last-of-type').on('click', function(){
        
        $( ".collaboration" ).each(function( index ) {
            
            if($('.collaboration').css('display') == 'block'){
                $(this).fadeOut()
                $(this).next().fadeIn()
  
            }

        })
    })
```

Is there a way to stop the each() from running when it is executed once and then run again when the click action happens?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="collaborations">
      <p class="arrow"><</p>
        <div class="collaboration">
            <img src="./img/test.png" />
            <p>Text</p>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Visit</button></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collaboration">
            <img src="./img/test.png" />
            <p>Text</p>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Visit</button></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collaboration">
             <img src="./img/test.png" />
             <p>Text</p>
             <a href="#" target="_blank"><button>Visit</button></a>
        </div>

        <p class="arrow">></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the html to show what your problem is ? It's hard to tell without it

Comment: Hi caroline4321! If you're able to put together a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) that shows the problem (maybe adding some `console.log` statement to help illustrate), that would be super helpful!

Comment: @Axnyff Yes, I have added it to the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

You could solve this by not iterating through the `.collaboration`s at all.

The key thing is that you need to keep track of which one is currently being shown.
If you know that, then what your click handler can do is show the next one and hide the current one.

I would suggest doing that with a class `.active` on the same div as `.collaboration`. You can then select the next div by `$('.active').next().addClass('.active')`, and deselect by `$('.active').removeClass('.active')`.

You might need to store a reference to your first element before you select the next one

#### Example

Here's a quick example of how this might work: https://codepen.io/juancaicedo/pen/LYGgPWa

I moved around the html to group all the collaborations into a div by themselves.

#### Other approaches

You'll find that you have to think through some other behaviors with the solution above. For example, in my example, there is a moment when two items are on the screen, causing their container div to grow and later shrink.

For these reasons, I don't like handling presentation from within javascript (i.e. using jquery's `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`).

If you can find a way to instead using only css, I think that's preferable. Here's an example using css transitions
https://codepen.io/juancaicedo/pen/ZEQqzrR

Comment: I think I understand, but I would like a code example if possible. Thank you!

Comment: @caroline4321 I've updated with an example and an alternate approach 

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method of `jQuery` can be stopped whenever you want by returning false inside of the callback, so you can probably fix your code by doing this:

```
$('.arrow:last-of-type').on('click', function(){

    $( ".collaboration" ).each(function( index ) {

        if($('.collaboration').css('display') == 'block'){
          $(this).fadeOut()
          $(this).next().fadeIn()
          return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but then the each won't run again, when the click action is done again

Comment: It seems weird the each wouldn't be called, did you try using a console.log